# why my code does not work in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am very very new to phonegap android app developing. I have configured everything after huge trying. Now I am learning to coding in phonegap.

Recently I got a javascript code for phonegap. which should display an alert notification. But it is not showing . It only shows html codes results. My code is below

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>

    <title>First App</title>
  <script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>

  <script>
     function onLoad(){

          document.addEventListener("deviceready",
onDeviceReady, true);
     }

     function onDeviceReady(){
navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working!!");
     }

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="onLoad();">

       <h1>Welcome to PhoneGap</h1>

       <h2>Edit assets/www/index.html</h2>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.prompt follow this link, it should help you

Comment: Does your device ready event fires?

Comment: no , my device does not fire ready event .

Comment: So you cordova file is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have included the right permissions in app/AndroidManifest.xml

If it doesn't works try with this:

```
function onDeviceReady(){       
    $(document).ready(function(e) {               
        navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working!!");       
    });
}
```

You should check [docs for 2.2.0](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification)

By the other hand I recommend you tu use a newer phonegap version.

Comment: its not working. it only shows

"       <h1>Welcome to PhoneGap</h1>

       <h2>Edit assets/www/index.html</h2>"

Comment: Can I ask you why to use 2.2.0 version? also remember that you need to add jquery to use $.(document).ready(...)

Comment: firstly I have downloaded latest version of phonegap. But I could not found cordova.jar on there. So I have downloaded old version of phonegap.
I have added jquery also.

Comment: If you use the latest phonegap version (3.2) you have to install nodeJS and use the phonegap build tools to compile the app for each platform, then it creates everything you need to start developing your project (folders and files...) check this [link](http://phonegap.com/install/) for install an this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) to configure your system to use phonegap Build.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Here are some points that you need to check:

- Make sure you have included `cordova-2.2.0.js` file in your application
  folder.
- Make sure you have mentioned the correct cordova file name in your
   tag. For ex.,  if you have included `cordova-3.0.0.js` in your
  application folder. You should mention the same file name in your
  script tag.
- You can try placing the `onDeviceReady()` function before the `onLoad()`
  function and check whether it makes any impact. Try placing a
  `console.log()` in the deviceready function.